# Editable GridView in Webforms MVP

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, mvp

I'm creating a WebForms website using the MVP design pattern.

I need to have a GridView or a Table that represents what's in my database table. This needs to be editable. Previously I've done this with GridViews with commandname = "edit", and handling things in code behind (I had to do very little). How do I handle this with MVP?

I'm passing the GridView to my model, where I populate it, then return it. How and where should I make the GridView editable? Do I have to write my own solution or can i still use the commandname = "edit" functionality?

Comment: `How do I handle this with MVP` Are you using third party framework along with ASP.Net Web Form?

Comment: nope, I'm just following the design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to give BulkEditGrid a try.

http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Current/Source/RealWorld.Grids/BulkEditGridView.cs

I use this extensively in a large WebForms application and it works great.